# Mutability of Python Generator Expressions versus List and Dictionary Comprehension: Nested Dictionary Weirdness

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I am using Python 3.5 to create a set of generators to parse a set of opened files in order to cherry pick data from those files to construct an object I plan to export later.  I was originally parsing through the entirety of each file and creating a list of dictionary objects before doing any analysis, but this process would take up to 30 seconds sometimes, and since I only need to work with each line of each file only once, I figure its a great opportunity to use a generator. However, I feel that I am missing something conceptually with generators, and perhaps the mutability of objects within a generator.

My original code that makes a list of dictionaries goes as follows:

```
parsers = {}
# iterate over files in the file_name file to get their attributes
for dataset, data_file in files.items():
    # Store each dataset as a list of dictionaries with keys that
    # correspond to the attributes of that dataset 
    parsers[dataset] = [{attributes[dataset][i]: value.strip('~') 
                         for i, value in enumerate(line.strip().split('^'))}
                         for line
                         in data_file]
```

And I access the the list by calling:

```
>>>parsers['definitions']
```

And it works as expected returning a list of dictionaries. However when I convert this list into a generator, all sorts of weirdness happens.

```
parsers = {}
# iterate over files in the file_name file to get their attributes
for dataset, data_file in files.items():
    # Store each dataset as a list of dictionaries with keys that
    # correspond to the attributes of that dataset 
    parsers[dataset] = ({attributes[dataset][i]: value.strip('~') 
                         for i, value in enumerate(line.strip().split('^'))}
                         for line
                         in data_file)
```

And I call it by using:

```
>>> next(parsers['definitions'])
```

Running this code returns an index out of range error.

The main difference I can see between the two code segments is that in the list comprehension version, python constructs the list from the file and moves on without needing to store the comprehensions variables for later use.

Conversely, in the generator expression the variables defined within the generator need to be stored with the generator, as they effect each successive call of the generator later in my code.  I am thinking that perhaps the variables inside the generator are sharing a namespace with the other generators my code creates, and so each generator has erratic behavior based on whatever generator expression was run last, and therefore set the values of the variables last.

I appreciate any thoughts as to the reason for this issue!

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?  It might be helpful . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the problem is when you're building the dictionaries.

```
attributes[dataset][i]
```

Note that with the list version, `dataset` is whatever `dataset` was at that particular turn of the `for` loop.  However, with the generator, that expression isn't evaluated until *after* the for loop has completed, so `dataset` will have the value of the *last* dataset from the `files.items()` loop...

Here's a super simple demo that hopefully elaborates on the problem:

```
results = []
for a in [1, 2, 3]:
    results.append(a for _ in range(3))

for r in results:
    print(list(r))
```

Note that we always get `[3, 3, 3]` because when we take the values from the generator, the value of `a` is `3`.

Comment: That's it! Thank you for the help, the provided demo helped a lot in getting me to wrap my head around the issue.  I was getting inconsistent behavior where sometimes it would display each dictionary correctly most likely because I was iterating over a dictionary, and so my generators would work when a sufficiently long attribute list was called as the last element (dictionaries not being ordered of course).  Also I've never seen the underscore used outside of the interpreter, I may try to incorporate that in the future to save on line space, thank you.